# Keras ignores the input_shape provided to the first layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I build a simple model like this, specifying an input shape of `(32, 32, 1)` to the first (and only) layer:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, input_shape=(32, 32, 1))
  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv(x)
    return x

model = Model()
```

Now when I call

```
print(model.summary())
```

I get the following error

```
This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()`
with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

despite the fact that `input_shape` is indeed specified.

The model also happily takes input with non-conforming shapes:

```
x = np.zeros((1, 24, 24, 1), dtype=np.float32)
model(x)  # OK!
```

Does this mean that despite what the documentation says, `input_shape` specification to the first layer is simply ignored? How to enforce this value?

*(My TF version is 2.1.0).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing the Sequential and Functional APIs.

Here you subclass your model, there is no graph of layers, only Python code run in the `call()` method ; so the `summary()` has no clue about what layers it will go through in the future.

If you really want to subclass `Model`, you can do something like this:

```
model_ = Model()
inputs = tf.keras.input(shape=(32,32,1))
outputs = model_(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

And you'll get the `summary()` display the correct input and output shape.

You can check [this blog post](https://medium.com/tensorflow/what-are-symbolic-and-imperative-apis-in-tensorflow-2-0-dfccecb01021) if you want more info on this. Hope it helps,

EDIT (for clarification following comment):

- When you use the imperative API:

  > Most debugging will happen during the model definition phase, not during execution. You have the guarantee that any model that compiles, will run. This enables faster iteration, and easier debugging.
- When you use the symbolic API (subclass Model):

  > There are almost no checks run on inputs or inter-layer compatibility, so a lot of the debugging burden moves from the framework to the developer when using this style.

Comment: In particular, quoting from the blog post :
> There are almost no checks run on inputs or inter-layer compatibility, so a lot of the debugging burden moves from the framework to the developer when using this style.

Comment: This makes sense for `.summay()`, which happens before anything is run. What about the call to `model(x)`, though? Shouldn't it have all the information it needs to fail?

Comment: Checks aren't performed ; most of them are skipped because we don't want to burden the code with test during execution (= training), that would slow it down. When we have a graph build phase, we can do the checks at that time (which has no performance impact on training). See my edit

Comment: Thanks. I understand the rationale. I do think the API is broken though.

Comment: I see what you mean - but performance is often a key issue in deep learning trainings and you don't want to do a check every time you go through that `call()` function (remember you run Python code, it doesn't know if it's the first of 1000th time it goes through the function, so you will check the input size thousands of times). I think the way the devs intend it is "ok, we give you a way to have more flexibility if you don't want to use our imperative API, but you have to know what you're doing"

Comment: Of course -- but then perhaps it should take another name, or be set at a different place. Also, I checked if the behavior is different when actually constructing a graph -- it is not, in which case they is simply no excuse not to make this check once during graph construction.